# How to write Date range query in H2 using jooq

Tags: java, sql, ibatis, jooq

I'm using mybatis library to execute native sql queries.
I'm using jooq to generate dynamic sql queries for different dialects.

Syntax:

```
condition = condition.and(DSL.field("START_TIME_").between("2014-10-12")
                                    .and("2014-10-12"));

Error:
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT * FROM ACT_HI_PROCINST WHERE (DELETE_REASON_ IS NULL AND START_TIME_ BETWEEN CAST(:[*]1 AS VARCHAR) AND CAST(:2 AS VARCHAR))
    LIMIT ? OFFSET ? "; expected "NOT, EXISTS, INTERSECTS, SELECT, FROM"; SQL statement:

select * 
from ACT_HI_PROCINST 
where (DELETE_REASON_ is null and START_TIME_ between cast(:1 as varchar) and cast(:2 as varchar))
```

Comment: It is hard to say from what you've posted so far, what the problem could be. Apparently, you're using jOOQ along with ibatis, but why? and how? Can you please provide more information to see what's going on?

Comment: In order to be able to help you, it would really be useful if you posted all the Java code that is relevant to the question. E.g., I suspect you are using jOOQ to render a SQL statement, and then pass that SQL string to iBatis. Please post all that code